# How to craft the maps for showing local isometries in general?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to understand the following example where they prove that $x$ and $x^*$ are locally isometric.

> [image]

Questions:

- How do people come up with these maps to prove local isometries? Is this just a silly example where we are lucky in having a simple map for that parametrization?
- Shouldn't it be $u=\cosh(v)$

Comment: Why do you say cosh?

Comment: @TedShifrin I naively thought that the objective was to (at least in this case) make both parametrizations equal.

Comment: Not at all. You want to make the first fundamental forms equal at corresponding points. You also want a valid change of coordinates (diffeomorphism). $\sinh$ is a one-to-one function; $\cosh$ most certainly is not.

Comment: @TedShifrin But then, the "objective" is to force both parametrizations to have identical first fundamental form? But then, how do I know when it's not possible at all to force it?

Comment: You will learn more as you continue reading. Curvature is a clue. But since the local isometry may be a very complicated function of $(u,v)$, this is in general a hard question.